# put all the items containing a certain string in a dataframe in another column

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe I have right now looks like this

```
In[1]: df
Out[1]:
index    yesterday    today    tomorrow   
1        apple_1      banana_3 cherry_4   
2        pear_2       apple_4  blueberry_1 
3        kiwi_3       orange_6 banana_2   
4        apple_1      melon_3  banana_4
```

I want to record all the apples and put it in another column/series like

```
index    yesterday    today    tomorrow    apple
1        apple_1      banana_3 cherry_4    apple_1
2        pear_2       apple_4  blueberry_1 apple_4
3        kiwi_3       orange_6 banana_2    nan
4        apple_1      melon_3  banana_4    apple_2
```

1. IDK which column will contain an apple
2. IDK what else is with the apple

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `startswith` then `where` mask then as nan and do `ffill`

```
df['new'] = df.where(df.apply(lambda x : x.str.startswith('apple'))).ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]
df
Out[149]: 
      yesterday     today     tomorrow      new
index                                          
1       apple_1  banana_3     cherry_4  apple_1
2        pear_2   apple_4  blueberry_1  apple_4
3        kiwi_3  orange_6     banana_2      NaN
4       apple_1   melon_3     banana_4  apple_1
```

Comment: Looks good! just one question, what if there are nan values in the original dataframe? it's giving me errors like Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @IRK df.where(df.fillna('').apply(lambda x : x.str.startswith('apple'))).ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]